# Chrome 69 and 70 goes unresponsive after a while behind corporate proxy

Tags: google-chrome, browser, proxy, firewall

Many users on OSX behind a corporate firewall report that Chrome will work fine for a while, then suddenly all URLS get an infinite spinner and eventually a `Page Unresponsive` popup. Force quitting and restarting chrome does not fix it, only a reboot does. All other apps like Safari continue to work fine. When I inspect web traffic with Charles, I see that the HTML for google.com comes back fine, but the page never renders. This was never an issue before Chrome 69. I verified this by downgrading and chrome never saw the issue. It's so bad we've all switched to Safari or Firefox. Terrible...

Any suggestions or ways to debug this? Chrome user support is of course unresponsive.

Comment: One of the things that changed was the Chrome login behavior.  Perhaps they are crashing while waiting to authenticate on a (blocked) Chrome login.  To confirm, intentionally log out of Chrome and see if the issue continues.

Comment: Login state has no impact. Even a fresh install has this issue.